# Надо ли ставить запятую после слова "однажды"?

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли ставить запятую после слова "однажды" в таких случаях, как например:

*Однажды, я в саду...*

Answer (score 3):

Для постановки запятой нет никаких причин.

Из толкового словаря:

ОДНАЖДЫ, нареч. 1. Один раз. Я видел вас только о. Такое случается лишь о. Я не о. говорил тебе об этом. 2. Как-то раз, когда-то. О. заговорили о давно забытом событии. О. я понял всю правоту этих слов и с тех пор ни разу не забывал о них. О. мы все пили чай на террасе. 3. Когда-нибудь. Пройдут годы, и о. ты проснёшься знаменитым. Уверяю вас, о. наступит момент полного прозрения! О. ты вспомнишь обо мне и загрустишь.